# The position of a particle at the time t > 0 is represented by $s(t) = \frac {1}{3}t^3- \frac {7}{2}t^2+20t-10$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

At which time particle is speeding up?

From my experience I think velocity is calculated by taking first derivative s'(t), which is $s'(t)=t^2-7t+20$ and acceleration calculated by taking second derivative S''(t) which is $s''(t)=2t-7$.

How to find at which time it speeding up?

Comment: Be careful with the "speeding up". In general, a particle with $s''(t_0)> 0$ is really "slowing down" at time $t_0$ if $s'(t_0) < 0$. (Because the speed is actually decreasing at this point!) If "speeding up" means the speed (not just velocity!) is increasing, you want the times $t$ such that $s''(t)$ and $s'(t)$ have the *same sign*, rather than just times where $s''(t) > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s''(t) >0$ if $t >\frac 7 2$ so it is speending up for $t >\frac 7 2$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, "speeding up" refers to positive acceleration. Therefore, you want to find the second derivative of $s$, i.e. $s''(t)$, and find for which values of $t$ we have $s''(t) > 0$.

This is best approached by considering the roots of the equation, and the behavior on other side of the roots. Since $s$ is a cubic, $s''$ will be linear, so one side of its root (of which there is only one) it will be negative (slowing down) and on the other $s''$ will be positive (speeding up).

Determine that and you will have an infinite interval, from that root, to the corresponding infinity, on which the particle speeds up.

Answer (score 1):

"speed" does not have direction; velocity does.

$\text{velocity } = s'\\
\text {speed } = |s'|$

$s' = t^2 - 7t + 20$

$s' > 0 $ for all $t.$

That makes things easier.  Then we only need to know when $s'' > 0$

$s'' = 2t - 7 > 0\\
t > \frac 72$

Comment: Problem specifically mentions "speeding up", which means increase of speed or acceleration.

Comment: If you are traveling to the right, and your acceleration is positive, you are speeding up.  If you are traveling to the left, and your acceleration is positive, you are slowing down.  If you are traveling to the left and your acceleration is negative, you are slowing down.

Answer (score 1):

Equate this equation to $zero $ to find the time it starts speeding up in other words"accelarating"
$s′′(t)=2t−7$ 
$2t−7=0$ 
$2t=7$ 
$t=\frac 72$ , that's the time it speeds up.